# Wordpress Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on this server

Tags: wordpress, permissions, admin-ajax

I have a portfolio when I click on the filter button it gives me this error :
You don't have permission to access `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` on this server.

[image: Apache Forbidden response]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's possibly a poorly written plugin, or theme that hasn't setup the AJAX call for use via the frontend, WordPress code using AJAX needs to be told whether to grant access via the frontend, backend or both.

Comment: A link to the page in question would allow us to debug the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have permission to access that file.

That likely means that you need to log into your server and change the permissions on that file. If it's Linux, and you can get to command-line, just use `chmod`:

```
chmod 774 /path/to/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

If it's some other configuration, you may need to ask another question, or update this one with those details if you can't figure it out. A question like that may actually be better suited for StackOverflow's sister site, StackExchange.

Comment: "better suited for StackOverflow's sister site, StackExchange" - Which sister site is that?

Comment: @MrWhite That was a long time ago. I probably meant Server Fault https://serverfault.com/